# displaying page with objects that may not exist?

Tags: django

So I have a page that is used to view an album page that also calls the artist id to display the associated artist of the album.

In my database, 'Artist' and 'Band' are two different models.

I am calling the artist id in this format :

```
href="{% url 'artist_details' Artist_id=Album.Artist.id %}"
```

In views.py :

```
artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, pk=Artist_id)
```

So when loading an album page that does not contain an artist, but rather a band, is there a way to get around the NoReverseMatch error that happens due to there not being a valid artist id? (because it gets the band id instead)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the album has no artist, then it probably doesn't make sense to render the link at all, so wrap it in an `if` block:

```
{% if Album.Artist %}
    <a href="{% url 'artist_details' Artist_id=Album.Artist.id %}"></a>
{% endif %}
```

On an unrelated note, you might consider following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable naming - it's generally discouraged in Python to use camel case for variable names.